# How to use Switch case in React js functional component inside return efficiently by reusing?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I want to use Switch case in React js functional component.
I want an efficient way of using it.

I have this code snippet:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FormUserDetails from './FormUserDetails';

function UserForm() {
    const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

    const nextStep = () => {
        setStep(prevState => prevState + 1)
    }
    const previousStep = () => {
        setStep(prevState => prevState - 1)
    }

    switch (step) {
        case 1:
            return (
                <div>
                    <FormUserDetails
                    />
                    <button onClick={() => nextStep()}>
                        next
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => previousStep()}>
                        previous
                    </button>
                </div>
            )
        case 2:
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>{step}</h1>
                    <button onClick={() => nextStep()}>
                        next
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => previousStep()}>
                        previous
                    </button>
                </div>
            )
        default:
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Final</h1>
                </div>
            )
    }
}
export default UserForm
```

This code is working fine.
However, in the return

```
                <button onClick={() => nextStep()}>
                    next
                </button>
                <button onClick={() => previousStep()}>
                    previous
                </button>
```

I am repeating this code. I just want to know an efficient code structure to reuse these lines with every switch case.

Comment: why don't you create a new component and use it? so in final you will have only 1 line (this component's tag)

Comment: Is it possible to do this within this file?

Comment: of course, just declare a variable as this jsx code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a little more code refactoring, factoring the buttons into a reusable component.

```
const StepButtons = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <button onClick={nextStep}>next</button>
    <button onClick={previousStep}>previous</button>
  </Fragment>
);
```

Result

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import FormUserDetails from './FormUserDetails';

function UserForm() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");

  const nextStep = () => {
    setStep(prevState => prevState + 1);
  };

  const previousStep = () => {
    setStep(prevState => prevState - 1);
  };

  const StepButtons = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <button onClick={nextStep}>next</button>
      <button onClick={previousStep}>previous</button>
    </Fragment>
  );

  switch (step) {
    case 1:
      return (
        <div>
          <FormUserDetails />
          <StepButtons />
        </div>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{step}</h1>
          <StepButtons />
        </div>
      );
    default:
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Final</h1>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
export default UserForm
```

Comment: I was looking for exactly something like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new component in a different file (if you want to distinguish this component of course)

```
import React from 'react'

export default function NavigationButtons(props) {
  return (
    <>
        <button onClick={props.nextStep}>
          next
        </button>
        <button onClick={props.previousStep}>
          previous
        </button>
     </>
)}
```

and then use it like this

```
<NavigationButtons nextStep={nextStep} previousStep={previousStep}/>
```

Comment: Thanks. this is another way to do this as well.

Comment: yes i saw it. if you want to have it only included in that component, then the other one is the preferred one :)

Comment: I appreciate your help.